# Open Layers issue with markers changing coordinates

Tags: asp.net, .net, openlayers

I have an issue that is driving me crazy.  I have an openlayers map project that works fine.  I took this concept code and moved it to a project that utilizes .Net and the projection for the markers/icons get messed up.

```
    //set the Icon/Marker that will be used
    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      opacity: 0.8,
      src: '<%=PinMarkerImage%>'
    }))
  });
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: iconStyle
  });



//we will zoom the map to fit the locations after we create
    //the map
  var mapObj = new ol.Map({
      layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }), vectorLayer],
      target: document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
        zoom: 12
      })
    });
    alert(vectorSource.getExtent());
    mapObj.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), { padding: [75, 40, 40, 75], constrainResolution: false });

//I pass in an object one at a time to populate the features
  function changeMapOption(oBranch, i) {
    // alert('selected');
    var long = oBranch.Longitude;
    var lat = oBranch.Latitude;
    alert(long + '  ' + lat);
    //lastCord = ol.proj.transform([coord[0], coord[1]], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
      geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([long, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')), //ol.proj.fromLonLat([long, lat])),
      id: oBranch.Id,
      title: oBranch.Name,
      address: oBranch.Address + ", " + oBranch.City + ", " + oBranch.State + " " + oBranch.ZipCode
    });

    //alert(iconFeature.getGeometry());
    vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);

    //mapObj.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), { padding: [75, 40, 40, 75], constrainResolution: false });
    //target = mapObj.getTarget();
    //This will zoom the map to fit all of the vector Sources in vectorSource
    //alert(vectorSource.getExtent());
    //mapObj.addOverlay(popup);
    //jTarget = typeof target === "string" ? $("#" + target) : $(target);
    //element = document.getElementById('popup');
  }
```

I have the alerts set to check the Longitude and Latitude.  These are correct. For this test run I have three objects that are populated, the Longitude and Latitudes are as follows:
-112.04883, 40.492104
-95.673328, 29.95752
-95.638558, 29.880014
When I run the code the alert for the vectorSource.getExtent() produces this:
-12473218.699582075,-8426499.834030088,-10646435.576762961,-6361484.120029401

And the markers show up off the lower coast of Chile.  The Latitude is wrong, yet the Longitude appears to be correct.

I could certainly use some guidance here.  This is driving me crazy.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple times, I came up with a solution that works.  Hopefully this will help someone down the line.

```
     function loadMarker(oBranch, i) {
            var sHTML = getMarkerInfoHtml(oBranch);
            var long = oBranch.Longitude * 1;
            var lat = oBranch.Latitude * 1;
            var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
              geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(([long, lat]))),
              index: oBranch.Id,
              id: oBranch.Id,
              title: oBranch.Name,
              address: sHTML     //oBranch.Address + ", " + oBranch.City + ", " + oBranch.State + " " + oBranch.ZipCode
      });

      vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);         
  }
```

The key was these two lines:

```
var long = oBranch.Longitude * 1;
var lat = oBranch.Latitude * 1;
```

by adding the * 1 to the line it forces JavaScript to treat the variables properly as numeric.  It now places the markers in the correct location.